# SonarQube false bug? with Null Coalesce & string value assignment

Tags: c#, sonarqube, sonarlint

Sonar Qube is giving following error:
*Strings should not be concatenated using '+' in a loop* and suggesting to use string builder instead , which I feel is not required for this small operation.

```
   for (int i = 0; i < Products.Count; i++) {
     product[i].Name = product[i].Name ?? product[i].Description;
   }
```

This to me seems like a false positive as this is just an assignment of value in case left hand is null , with a right hand value of ?? operator.

I am unable to find any direct issues but rather related such as [reference](https://community.sonarsource.com/t/null-check-fallback-value-is-reported-as-bug-but-its-not/4313).

Edit: [image] Version of Sonar Qube enterprise edition 6.7

Comment: Are you sure that is the code that Sonar Qube is referring to?

Comment: Which version of  SonarQube is it? Does it understand C#8 syntax? Perhaps it is getting confused by the `??` operator?

Comment: Null coalescing operator was available in C#6. I couldn't reproduce this error in latest sonarlint.

Comment: @Crowcoder yes I've now attached a screenshot above.

Comment: @DavidG Sonar Qube enterprise edition 6.7

Comment: @Peska I cant reproduce it in standalone sonar list either. Issue is there in Sonar Qube report which runs on a hosted server with master branch